# Where can I get the STAP?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Those with the Collector's Edition of The Old Republic get a Single Trooper Aerial Platform:

> The STAP is a sleek and unique in-game vehicle you will acquire during your journeys.

*Where* do I acquire it during my journeys?  Does it differ per class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the Collectors or Digital Deluxe edition registered on your account, and re-log into the game, your character (every character you now have, or make in the future) will receive an in-game mail that includes all the appropriate items.

You do not need to be a specific level to receive them. But some, like the STAP speeder, have level requirements to use them. (Riding skill comes at level 25; and costs a decent amount of in-game credits. Make sure to save up!)

The STAP will work for any class.

EDIT: Changes to the game allow for legacy upgrades and cartel purchases that adjust the Riding Skill 1 to be available at much, much earlier levels.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed from the wording that it'd require questing but mail is much better.

Comment: Speeder training is 15 for Members, and with legacy perks, can be brought down to 10.